# Sum of Values with Specific Condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to ask a question about pandas/python. Let us say I have two columns. I want to find the cumulative sum of values of my first column until the value of my second column reaches a specific value. I think it would be a better option to explain the question by using just a small example.

**I have:**

```
 A    B
 1    0
 2    0
 2    0
 1    1
 2    0
 3    0
 3    0
 5    1
```

**I want:**

```
 A.   B.   C
 1.   0.   1
 2.   0.   3 (1+2)
 2.   0.   5 (1+2+2)
 1.   1.   6 (1+2+2+1) So, cumulative sum should stop here, because B reaches 1 now. 
 2.   0.   2 So, cumulative sum should begin again.
 3.   0.   5 (2+3)
 3.   0.   8 (2+3+3)
 5.   1.   13 (2+3+3+5) So, cumulative sum should stop again, because B reaches 1 again.
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) with another `cumsum` for groups:

```
df['C'] = df.groupby(df['B'].eq(1).iloc[::-1].cumsum())['A'].cumsum()
#if only 0 and 1 values in B
#df['C'] = df.groupby(df['B'].iloc[::-1].cumsum())['A'].cumsum()
print (df)
   A  B   C
0  1  0   1
1  2  0   3
2  2  0   5
3  1  1   6
4  2  0   2
5  3  0   5
6  3  0   8
7  5  1  13
```

**Details**:

Compare by `1` and change order by indexing with `iloc`:

```
print (df['B'].eq(1).iloc[::-1])
7     True
6    False
5    False
4    False
3     True
2    False
1    False
0    False
Name: B, dtype: bool
```

Create groups by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
print (df['B'].iloc[::-1].cumsum())
7    1
6    1
5    1
4    1
3    2
2    2
1    2
0    2
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Very simple and great solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: can I use the same code for the standard deviation? I tried, however, got an error.

Comment: @Khalid - Do you need new column filled by `std`? Then use `df['C'] = df.groupby(df['B'].eq(1).iloc[::-1].cumsum())['A'].transform('std')`. If need aggregation - `df1= df.groupby(df['B'].eq(1).iloc[::-1].cumsum())['A'].std()`